# Activating Console window

Tags: c#, windows

I am opening Word from within a Console Application. How can I ensure the Console remains the active window, even after I have shown the Word Application?

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WordDocumentObject {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            _Application app = new Application();
            app.Visible = true;

            //Activate the console window here

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to use a call to the SetForegroundWindow API to get what you ask:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

full example is already in SO:

[bring a console window to front in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213480/bring-a-console-window-to-front-in-c)

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.