# Embed Selenium initiated chrome browser in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium

I have build a c# Windows Form application which required both automation and human interaction on the Chrome browser opened by selenium.

Currently 3 separate windows open
1. My Winform application
2. Selenium Console
3. The Chrome browser

I would like to embed both the console (will embed but hide from view) and the browser opened in the application itself. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50181992/embedding-selenium-chromedriver-in-windows-form) answer explaining how to embed the console application.

Comment: Add some code showing what you've done so far.

Comment: @simonC I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0):

The link you've provided gives you some example code to work off.
That allows you to embed the console in to your WinForms window.

I then found [this](https://www.joecolantonio.com/selenium-webdriver-visual-studio/) link, which goes a bit more in-depth in to the matter. 
Granted, the link is rather old but it should get you started in the right direction.

Regarding the links provided by the page I linked, Selenium provides NuGet packages for C#:

```
install-package selenium.webdriver
install-package selenium.webdriverbackendselenium
install-package selenium.support
```

That should at least provide you with a decent start.

Comment: My question was asking how i can embedd a selenium started web browser in a winform I know how to use selenium