# Bring console application window to front code explanation

Tags: c#, console

I need to bring the console from an C# form/console application to the front. I got the following code which will bring the console window to front from: [bring a console window to front in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213480/bring-a-console-window-to-front-in-c-sharp)

**However why does this code example also prints true** and how can I disable it?

```
public static void ToFront()
{
    string originalTitle = Console.Title;
    string uniqueTitle = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Console.Title = uniqueTitle;
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    IntPtr handle = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, uniqueTitle);
    Console.Title = originalTitle;
    Console.WriteLine(SetForegroundWindow(handle));
}
```

Comment: The **last line** is responsible for printing "true", you should change it to `SetForegroundWindow(handle)` from `Console.WriteLine(SetForegroundWindow(handle))` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your last line from

```
Console.WriteLine(SetForegroundWindow(handle));
```

to

```
SetForegroundWindow(handle);
```

What you had was executing the function and printing the resulting value.

Comment: Thanks! I missed that one ;)

Answer (score 1):

This line is the culprit:

```
Console.WriteLine(SetForegroundWindow(handle));
```

[SetForeGroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns a bool, which is cast to a string automatically by WriteLine, and printed out.

Replace it with:

```
SetForegroundWindow(handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out the return of SetForgroundWindow which returns true when it succeeds.  Just remove the class to console.writeline

```
Console.Title = originalTitle;
SetForegroundWindow(handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

```
SetForegroundWindow(handle);
```

not

```
Console.WriteLine(SetForegroundWindow(handle));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the title is unique within the desktop, add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic, then:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
....
Interaction.AppActivate(Console.Title);
```

Edit: Sorry I didn't completely read the question, but this is a simple way of bring an app to the foreground if the VB import doesn't offend you.