# bring console window to the front of the desktop

Tags: c#, wpf

I have C# console project, with WPF window. I want to switch between the two windows: the console and the WPF.So how can I bring my console window to the front of the desktop?

I succeeded to do it to the WPF with the `Activate` method. I tried also to use the following method from: [bring a console window to front in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213480/bring-a-console-window-to-front-in-c-sharp) and it did not work.

```
public static void ToFront()
{
    string originalTitle = Console.Title;
    string uniqueTitle = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Console.Title = uniqueTitle;
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    IntPtr handle = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, uniqueTitle);
    Console.Title = originalTitle;
    SetForegroundWindow(handle);
}
```

Comment: PInvoke to Win API via ```static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);``` normally works fine If you are able to find your consol window via ```FindWindowByCaption```so may be explain what did not work while try that fom the post you mentioned.

Comment: What does "did not work" mean exactly? Are you getting an exception or what happens?